# Центрирование среднего блока между двумя и автоматическая ширина

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день

Есть 3 блока: *div1*, *div2*, *div3*.
Как сделать так, чтобы ширина *div2* зависела от *div1* и *div3*? Если, к примеру, в *div3* добавляется какой нибудь новый контент, то ширина *div2* уменьшается и наоборот.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Такого эффекта можно добиться с помощью `flexbox`.
Устанавливаем родителю `display: flex`, а для *div_1* устанавливаем `flex: 1` (это означает, что блок будет иметь максимальную возможную ширину).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent-div {
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.parent-div_0 {
  background-color: red;
}
.parent-div_1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
}
.parent-div_2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-div parent-div_0">Люблю тосты с сыром</div>
  <div class="parent-div parent-div_1"></div>
  <div class="parent-div parent-div_2">Люблю пончики</div>
</div>
```

Примерно такого же эффекта можно добиться с помощью `display: table`:

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent-div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.parent-div_0 {
  background-color: red;
}
.parent-div_1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.parent-div_2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent-div parent-div_0">Люблю тосты с сыром</div>
  <div class="parent-div parent-div_1">Люблю торты</div>
  <div class="parent-div parent-div_2">Люблю пончики</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Конечно же хотелось бы узнать вариант без flex'сов но и за это огромное спасибо!